# Setting up QXC2 interaction with the geoserver, and not with the database, how to dynamically change the project files?

Tags: qgis, geoserver

I have a few questions about QWC2/QGIS Server

1. Is it possible to configure QGIS Server to interact with GeoServer, not with the database?
2. Is it possible to set, when opening a project, a transition to a specific object of the project layer? (automatic approach to the object)
3. Are there tools for dynamically updating project files in the scan folder?

Thanks!

After trying different ways and approaches, I failed to get what I wanted to see

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!